# The windows Phone Emulator wasn't able to set the VHD on the virtual machine:

Tags: windows-phone-8

Once running `Windows Phone 8` application I  get the following  error report:

```
Couldn't change synthetic disk drive of the virtual machine. 'Emulator WXGA.test' failed to add device 'Synthetic Disk Drive'.
'Emulator WVGA.test':Cannot attach storage media to the controller because the specific location is in use.
```

Comment: Reason is   every WP8 emulator running in virtual machine need for memory,So every default emulator manually memory allocated.   following steps:

Comment: virtual machine need memory,step 1) block your anti virus first.step2) start menu click Hyper-v manager.step 3) select your user account emulator.step 4)right click open settings-> IDEcontroller0 -> select Hard drive.step 5) virtual hard disk is empty so click New -> click next -> choose VHD click next->choose Dynamic expanding  click next-> write name  click next -> create new virtual blank hard disk space is maximum 10 GB is enough . click next and finish.Once create means select particular emulator in hyper-v manager double click and click start  means successfully run . run your wp8 app.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run this in a command prompt (as administrator) 
gpupdate /force